# No appropriate default constructor available - Visual Studio

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, default-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle {
  int width, height;
public:
  Rectangle(int x, int y) : width(x), height(y) {}
  int area(void) { return width * height; }
};

int main() {
  Rectangle obj (3, 4);
  Rectangle * foo, * bar, * baz;
  foo = &obj;
  bar = new Rectangle (5, 6);
  baz = new Rectangle[2] { {2,5}, {3,6} };
  cout << "obj's area: " << obj.area() << '\n';
  cout << "*foo's area: " << foo->area() << '\n';
  cout << "*bar's area: " << bar->area() << '\n';
  cout << "baz[0]'s area:" << baz[0].area() << '\n';
  cout << "baz[1]'s area:" << baz[1].area() << '\n';
  delete bar;
  delete[] baz;
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

This code executes in code blocks, but in Visual Studio, there is no appropriate default constructor available.

I tried searching for something similar here, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: You don't have a default constructor.  If you post the whole error and show the line it is complaining about you might get an answer.

Comment: `baz = new Rectangle[2] { {2,5}, {3,6} };` may give you problem on some compilers about default constructor.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you have and which compiler/version do you use with code blocks (code blocks is not a compiler; it is a development environment, that can be used with different compilers)?

Comment: Also please when asking about something that involves compiler errors, quote the errors _exactly_.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `operator new` and `operator new[]` and the way you pass arguments to constructors of newly built elements.

for ex: (Slightly modified version taken from wikipedia)

```
T *p = new T(42); //New T inited to T(42). (same syntax as constructors)
T *parray = new T[42];  //An array of 42 T, inited with T()
T *cpp11array = new T[3] {1, 2, 3};  //3 Ts, inited to T(1), T(2) and T(3) (C++11 only)
```

It seems your Visual Studio **is not** C++11 compliant. Hopefully there should be an option to enable C++11 std or you may want to install the latest compiler.

As side note, you should prefer an STL container (for ex: std::array or std::vector instead of naked pointer array).

```
vector<Rectangle> baz;
baz.push_back( Rectangle(2, 5) );
baz.push_back( Rectangle(3, 6) );
```